# Divs not findable after attaching display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

During the onLoad function I set several div elements with assignment of the CSS property display none to "invisible":

```
function hideContent() {
    laElements = document.getElementById("content").children;
    for (var i = 0; i < laElements.length; i++) {
        laElements[i].classList.add("hidden");
    }
}
```

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

At a later time I would like to set one of these s back to visible (by removing the CSS-class), but I have the problem that the `<div>` is not findable via "getElementbyId".
Instead, when I call the remove function, I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined".

When I'm accessing the overlaying `<div>` element there are no more children listed. Its seems like the property "display: none" makes the element disappear completely from the DOM.

Can anyone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?
When possible I would prefer a solution without jQuery.

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: Setting a div to `display:hidden` doesn't remove it from the DOM. You must be removing it elsewhere, or not adding it in the first place, or selecting it wrong in Javascript.

Comment: you are adding "hidden **class**" and trying to access it via `getElementById`. Or show us the html and other javascript part so that we can get more clearity.

Comment: I'm sorry that I not provide enough information.
Find the minimal example at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/703sna6w/15/)

The only difference - no error is logged there. I guess this means that I did something really stupid...

Comment: Use "visibility: hidden;" instead of "display:none;"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have classes instead of id for the div so in javascript you'd have to write `getElementByClass()`.